# Java, MySQL и отображение данных из таблиц

Tags: java, mysql, консоль

Добрый день.

Есть такой метод:

```
public void showTable(ResultSet rs) {
    try {
        ResultSetMetaData rsmd = rs.getMetaData();
        for (int i = 1; i < rsmd.getColumnCount(); i++) {
            System.out.print(rsmd.getColumnName(i) + "\t");
        }
        while (rs.next()) {
            System.out.println();
            for (int i = 1; i < rsmd.getColumnCount(); i++) {
                System.out.print(rs.getString(i) + "\t");
            }
        }
        System.out.println();
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Который, как вы понимаете, выводит на консоль метаданные из таблиц. Так вот, он делает все хорошо, но не выводит название последнего столбца.

Почему?

Comment: Разве цикл не с 0 надо начинать?

Comment: @АлександрМартынцев можно хоть с -666 начинать.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Вы учли, что нумерация в `ResultSetMetaData` начинается с единицы, но забыли про то, что она должна заканчиваться ровно на последнем элементе, а не до него. То есть, необходимо исправить условие цикла:

```
for (int i = 1; i <= rsmd.getColumnCount(); i++) {
```

Comment: Да. Спасибо нашел. Внимание к деталям воспитывать в себе должен я.